# How to use Swift set remove at method?

Tags: swift, set

I'm playing around with different data structures in Swift and I'm curious to know how to use the remove at function for Sets.  The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/2831656-remove) says the method accepts an index in which I though would be number however this doesn't work.  Can someone show me the proper way to use this method?

```
var girlfriends: Set = ["Karlie", "Francis", "Mya", "Zoe", "Daisy", "Bambi"]

print(girlfriends)

for _ in 1...10 {
    print(girlfriends)
}

girlfriends.insert("Joyce")

print(girlfriends)

girlfriends.insert("Bambi")

print(girlfriends)

girlfriends.insert("Vicki")

print(girlfriends)

// doesn't compile  var beach = girlfriends["Vicki"]

// doesn't compile girlfriends.remove(at: 2)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last two lines in Set operations has different approach to get and remove values. The following depicts how you can achieve this.

```
//To get the value 

 if let beach = girlfriends.first(where: { $0 == "Vicki" }) {
      print(beach) //here you will get the value
 }

 //To remove it at certain index, which is different then Int index like on array

 if let indexToRemove = girlfriends.index(of: "Vicki") {
        girlfriends.remove(at: indexToRemove)
 }

       //OR

 girlfriends.remove("Vicki")
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `remove(at:)` doesn’t receives an integer, it receives a `Set<Element>.Index`. You can use [firstIndex(of:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/set/2996833-firstindex) to get the index of the element you want to remove.